# Exchange calendar busy

Tags: exchange

We share the CEO's calendar with everybody in the company. However, only VPs should be able to see appointment details, other persons should only be able to see free/busy information. Where in MS Exchange can I configure such a system?

Comment: I don't think Exchange allows a calendar to be shared and the event details not to be shared.

Comment: It works for "private" appointments, however, then nobody can see the appointment details.

Comment: The best way to handle something like this is for there to be a dedecated calendar with the event but no appointment details.  What you want isn't possible in Exchange.  The use case of sharing an appointment but not the appointment details is likely very small.

Comment: Why is this use case small?
Everybody should know if I'm available or not but not everybody should know *why* I'm not available. This seems like a legit mainstream use case.

Comment: I have never been in a situation where my supervisor has shared his calendar but has choosen not to share the details of the meeting ( i.e. the email for the event ) with his employees.  A dedecated calendar for this purpose could be used with limited work by a secretary.  For the VPs the CEO could simple share his calendar.